# Infinite printing when trying to use a loop

Tags: java

new to programming.

I have a class in java and i'm trying to write this program but it's printing none-stop and it's even bugging my browser! (Im using an online ide)

my instructions: 
Q: how much do you love me?
Below 10 : wrong answer
equal to 10 and more = good answer

I know how to do it but I dont want the program to stop every time i write an answer. I want the program to keep running until i have a 10 +. So i can always input until it's 10+ out of 10.

this is my lines :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println ("how much do you love me out of 10");
    int num1 = input.nextInt();

    while (true) 
    if (num1 <= 9) {
    System.out.println("Wrong answer");
    }
       else {
       System.out.println ("Good answer");
       }
 }
}
```

Comment: Move the line with input.nextInt *inside* your while loop

Comment: And then add the exit step after printing "Good answer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Out of 10, how much do you love me?");
        int input = 0
        while (input <= 9) {
            input = scanner.nextInt();
            if (input <= 9) {
                System.out.println("Wrong answer");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Good answer");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation: It loops until input is less **not** less than or equal to 9 (`while (input <= 9)`). Each time through the loop, it gets input and acts on it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: IT WORKED! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to move the `int num1 = input.nextInt();` statement inside your while loop, this will allow for a new input every time the while loop loops (iterates).

Second, if you are looking to run the program until `num1 >= 10`, then you could implement it in two ways.

```
while(num1 < 10) {
    num1 = input.nextInt();

    if(num1 >= 10) {
        System.out.println("Good answer");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong answer");
    }
}
```

or using the keyword `break`,

```
while(true) {
    num1 = input.nextInt();

    if(num1 >= 10) {
        System.out.println("Good answer");
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong answer");
    }
}
```

`break` simply escapes the loop it resides in when called

Hoped this helped

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Both worked but I preferred the second one. BUT, both of them, when i input an answer below 10, I dont see any " wrong answer". I need to type a number below 10 a second time to prompt the wrong answer line..